# Deducing columns of a matrix from a fact about the dimension of the column space

Tags: linear-algebra

If I know the column space of a matrix $A$ is a straight line (i.e. a 1d subspace), then what does this tell me about the columns of A?

Can I determine any information?

Perhaps the columns are all linearly dependent, since we can write the column space as the span of a single vector?

Comment: This is exactly what you can follow from that.

Comment: All columns are multiples of a single vector (that is the basis vector for column space), thus you deduce a far stronger conclusion: each pair of column vectors is linearly dependent.

Comment: Why are all the columns multiples of a single vector? Is it based on a row reduction?

Comment: @apkg There's need for row-reduction. The fact that the column space is 1-dimensional means that every element of the column space (which in particular includes every column) can be written as a multiple of a single vector. This comes down to the definition of dimension (or at least of a space being "one-dimensional")

Comment: Yes I understand now. if the columns or rows were not all linearly dependent, the columns or rows would span a larger space, obviously.